# How can I determine if my VPN is passing through UDP traffic?

Tags: vpn, udp

I have an client application that is unable to connect with it's server counterpart over a VPN connection.  Server is Windows SBS 2011, client is Windows 7 64bit Enterprise.  Using Windows VPN client.  I can ping the server and browse it's drives, but when the client application attempts to connect it fails immediately with a series of generic reasons (e.g. "Maybe the server isn't on" and "Maybe you are specifying an invalid IP address").  After speaking with the application support people they had me run a testing client/server pair of apps on the server and workstation to verify UDP traffic was being transmitted.  The test failed.

So now I need to figure out whether or not UDP traffic is passing through, and if not what I need to do to resolve that.

Comment: Believe it or not the _several reasons_ could be quite important.

Comment: "So now I need to figure out whether or not UDP traffic is passing through" - It seems to me that you've already determined that it isn't.

Comment: Wireshark/tcpdump, plus whatever your favorite tools is for generating traffic.

Comment: @Lain - good point, I have edited my question to clarify.  There is nothing telling in the errors reported, they are borderline insulting in the simplicity. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use netcat, you can download the windows version [here](http://joncraton.org/files/nc111nt.zip)

On one end of the VPN start a listener (-l for listen -u for UDP):

```
nc -lu <port>
```

On the other end test the UDP connection, text entered after issuing the nc command should appear on the listener terminal:

```
nc -u <litenerIP> <port>
```

here's a local test run in 2 separate terminals:

listener:

```
$ sudo nc -lu 99

hello
test
```

client:

```
$ sudo nc -u 127.0.0.1 99

hello
test
```

Comment: Great help!  I setup the pair on the LAN and everything worked as expected.  I then ran netcat from behind the VPN and the string is not echoed on the listener.  So UDP is blocked.  I will post another question asking how to resolve this now.  Thanks again!